# \title and \section have different fonts

Tags: titles, koma-script

If I compile the font of the `\title` command and the `\section` command are somehow different. Why is there another font used in the `\section` command? I want to have the font of the `\title` in all the `\section` commands.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsopn}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\title{Doppler-free Saturation Absorption Spectroscopy of Caesium}
\author{Example Name, Other Example, Another E.}

\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
---
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\setkomafont{title}{\bfseries}` by `\setkomafont{dispositon}{\bfseries}`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! What font is used in the \sections? Is it normal to have a different font in the \title than \section (for KOMA-script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a KOMA-Script the font of the title is normally set by `\usekomafont{title}` and `\huge`. The default setting of the font element `title` is `\usekomafont{disposition}`.

The element `disposition` is also used by all sectioning commands (before their own font elements). Its default setting is `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries`.

So with `\setkomafont{title}{\normalcolor\bfseries}` you change the settings only for the title. But if you replace this by

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
```

it affects also all sectioning commands.